# Scanf for multiple user inputs

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf, stdin

Apologizes I am very inexperienced with C. I have the following code:

```
char * a[BUF_SIZE]; 

scanf("%d", numberOf);
do {
    a[i] = (char *)malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN + 1);
    scanf("%s", a[i]);
    ++i;
} while(i < numberOf);
```

The idea is simple, read two inputs from stdin using scanf, the first being a single int, followed by some array of strings. Scanf works independently in both cases e.g. scanf("%d", numberOf) will store a digit and scanf("%s", a[i]) will store a set of strings into the array. However in conjunction reading an integer first into numberOf causes a segfault when reading in a set of strings. My question is why? I know its generally bad practice to use scanf, but I fail to see how reading in multiple inputs from stdin can cause a segfault in the resulting code. Much Thanks!

Comment: Decide on one language.

Comment: 1) You should check whether `numberOf > BUF_SIZE`. 2) Replace the do-while-loop with a for-loop. 3) On casting the return value of `malloc`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc 4) Call `free`.

Comment: @cad I agree with 1), as for 2) could you explain why exactly there would be an advantage in converting the looping semantics, I can't seem to find any reason to support a change other than readability, for 3) I am compiling with g++ as a user commented in the post "Considering that C++ compilers give better warnings than C compilers, making your code C++ compilable is worth the downside IMHO".

Comment: If you use a C++ compiler then why did you remove the C++ tag, keeping the C tag? When using C++ you should use `new` and `delete` instead, if you didn't know. On your question regarding the loop: every normal C programmer will instantly associate the for-loop with an index and such, thus making it more readable. Anyway, the more practical fact is that a do-while-loop runs at least one time; however, what if `numberOf == 0`?

Comment: @cad Awh, good point. As for the tags, it is a C language related question specifically. I'm not interested in a C++ language specific solution. Not specified in the post, so I can understand the confusion, my task has at least one input always, so I utilized a do-while simply because it's my first time exposed to the looping structure and I feel it's appropriate considering the loop should always run at least once. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the code, it looks like `numberOf` is an `int`. When using `scanf`, you want to pass it a pointer, so change `scanf("%d", numberOf);` to `scanf("%d", &numberOf);`

What `scanf` does is take the user input and put it into the memory address specified by the second parameter. When you provide an `int` as the second parameter, `scanf` tries to put user input into a memory address (specified by the `int`) that it may not own, causing the seg-fault.

Comment: Do you think you could explain why scanf causes a segfault when not passed a pointer for educational purposes? Much appreciated.

Comment: @user2808315: The value contained in `numberOf` is most likely not a valid pointer value (i.e., not an address that your code may write to), which *may* cause a segfault.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `&` operator in `scanf("%d", numberOf);` put it as `&numberOf`